# How to remove the older projects entries/list/history from the Visual Studio Opening Window?

Tags: visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-2022

All the Recently worked projects will be available in Visual Studio Opening window.
Even if the projects are removed from our file explorer, those names will exist in the VS Opening Window.

I'm able to delete those recent projects entries/history one at a time by using this option:

VS Opening Window
[image]

My Question is:

**How to delete all those history/entries at a time to see like the below window (screen)**?

VS Opening Window Clear
[image]

[image]

Comment: Should be as simple as *Open File Menu => Recent Files or Recent Projects => Clear All* have you tried that? There is also a extension that performs this duty [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GrzegorzKozub.ClearRecent)

Comment: Good Suggestion, and could you please tell which file path I should open in File Menu @Ramhound to see the Recent Files/Projects

Comment: Click “continue without code” should be self explanatory after that, or if that’s from a previous version (I don’t have a VS2019 handy), the file extension is an alternative solution.  The website that suggests the option to clear recent projects was clear if it was from VS2019 or not.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/amoINjV.png - After opening the VS, I'm getting this option! In the opening window (above screenshots) of the VS, clear option is not visible after installing the ClearRecent extension. Could you please show that if you have any version of VS like 2019 or 2022!

Comment: I have VS2021, however, there are some pretty big differences between VS2019 and VS2021.  I am not sure my VS2021 configuration is relevant.

Comment: VS 2022 does not have the 'Clear All' option any more in the Recent Files list.

Comment: There really should be an option to specify the "recent duration" (like show recent from last 7 or 30 days). And it should be possible to manually clearing all unpinned entries or all entries with invalid paths.,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an extension called [Clear Recent](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GrzegorzKozub.ClearRecent) which will do this for you.

See [this post](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/257178/how-can-i-clear-visual-studio-2019-file-mru.html) for more information.

Comment: Clear Recent is good and works after opening the VS IDE. There is an unanswered question at the end in that given [Post](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/257178/how-can-i-clear-visual-studio-2019-file-mru.html), how do we clear those recent files in the [Startup window of Visual Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFFci.png).